# How to extract text pdf from an url without downloading it in Python

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I'm currently extracting pdf from an API using requests.get. I don't want to download them but just to extract the text from them.

```py
response_pdf = requests.get(url, auth=TokenAuth(key))
text = convert_pdf_to_txt(response_pdf.content)
```

Here is the code for the function convert_pdf_to_txt:

```py
def convert_pdf_to_txt(filename):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    #codec ='ISO-8859-1'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = open(filename, 'rb')

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    text = str(text)
    text = text.replace("\\n", "")
    text = text.lower()

    return text
```

I get the following error: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

The response_pdf.content is a "class 'bytes'" object and i don't know how to extract the text from it.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Please add the full traceback for the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a bytestring to be interpreted as a filename to open, which is not good.

Instead, you can read the bytestring into `io.BytesIO()` and pass it in as `fp`:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(fp):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = "utf-8"
    # codec ='ISO-8859-1'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(
        rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams
    )

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(
        fp,
        pagenos,
        maxpages=maxpages,
        password=password,
        caching=caching,
        check_extractable=True,
    ):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    text = str(text)
    text = text.replace("\\n", "")
    text = text.lower()
    return text

response_pdf = requests.get(url, auth=TokenAuth(key))
pdf_stream = io.BytesIO(response_pdf.content)
text = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf_stream)
```

This has the additional nicety to it that you can *still* use it with files:

```py
with open('my_pdf', 'rb') as pdf_stream:
  text = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf_stream)
```